# How to do program keep running with checkpoint is failed

Tags: java, assert, serenity-bdd

I am using SenerityBdd + Java. I have some scenarios with a lot steps. When a step gets failure then my program stopped. It's so difficult when doing debug steps because program always stops with failed checkpoint. I also soft assertion lib of java.

Do you have any idea to mark step FAILED but program keep running when having failed checkpoint?

Comment: You can't. You can only optimize your time of realaunching that function which you are debugging. Like splitting your code to simpliest/shorter fragments and testing only fragments, try catch where you have error for application to run anyway, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **SoftAssertions** from **assertj** library.

Adding on to Szprota21's comment, you would need to handle all exceptions.

Assuming that all exceptions are handled for a failing step, you could use below structure in your step definition class to implement soft assertion using assertj library.

```
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Steps;

public class TestStepDefinitionClass {
    private SoftAssertions softAssertions;

    @Steps
    SomeClass SomeClass;
    
    // Before hook to initialize SoftAssertions object for every scenario
    @Before(order = 1)
    public void setUp() {
        softAssertions = new SoftAssertions();
    }

    // After hook to call assertAll() to invoke soft assertion for every scenario
    @After(order = 1)
    public void tearDown() {
        softAssertions.assertAll();
    }

    @Given("method1")
    public void method1() {
        // The below validation will fail, but since it is soft assertion, it will move on to the next step.
        softAssertions.assertThat(1).isEqualTo(2);
    }

    @Then("method2")
    public void pass2() {
        // assertion passed
        softAssertions.assertThat(2).isEqualTo(2);
    }

    @Then("method2")
    public void pass3() {
        // assertion passed
        softAssertions.assertThat(3).isEqualTo(3);
    }
}
```

Link for [assertj maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core)

To learn about usages and common mistakes, follow [Assertj documentation](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-incorrect-usage)